# Optional relation for entities in doctrine/symfony

Tags: symfony, database-design, doctrine

Assume we have an entity "ticket". That entity can be related 1:1 to an entity "customer" OR to an entity "company", but never to both, but the ticket can also have no relation to one of these both entities at all.

How is this possible in doctrine/symfony?

Comment: While this question doesn't show that many research effort, it is clear and useful. It isn't worth so many downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know your model but at database level the foreign keys in the ticket entity(customer_id and company_id) should be nullables in order to let one of them or both empty. At doctrine/entity level the only way is to use a [validator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html) option to check your requirements.

I guess wich better suits you is the [callback](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html) validator but is your to decide